# Web API POSTing XML object is always null

Tags: c#, xml, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've seen a few similar questions to this but none of the solutions have helped me.

This code works perfectly when I'm passing a JSON payload. But with an XML load, the passed object to the controllers POST method is always NULL.

My console app simply makes a POST http request to my ASP MVC Controller and at this point the passed XML payload object is always null.

This is my console application showing the http request object being set and the XML Xdocument payload being constructed:

```
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
    XElement clientRequestElement = new XElement(xmlns + "PLTSActivation",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
            new XElement(xmlns + "iSIClientID", iid.ToString()),
            new XElement(xmlns + "organizationId", ooid),
            new XElement(xmlns + "statusDescription", "Success"));

    doc.Add(clientRequestElement);

    return doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}


public static void PostXML()
{
    string _URL = "http://localhost:24689/api/PTShandler/postxml";

    string _OOID = "TEST";
    string convertedJSONPayload = "";

    var payloadObj = new
    {
        XmlPayload = ConstructProvisioningRequest(99783971, _OOID)
    };

    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_URL);
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("ORGOID", _OOID);
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Culture", "en-US");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(payloadObj.ToString());
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is my PTShandler controller showing the POST method:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public string PostXML(object xmlPayload)
{

    //*****The 'xmlPayLoad' object is always null*****
    List<SplitXML> returnedPopulatedXMLObject = SetXMLstrings(XDocument.Parse(xmlPayload.ToString()));

    foreach (var XMLitem in returnedPopulatedXMLObject)
    {
        _ClientID = XMLitem.ISIClientID;

        _OrganizationID = XMLitem.OrganizationID;

        _Status = XMLitem.Status;
    }

    string stringXDoc;

    return stringXDoc = "POSTed";
}
```

This is my Global.asax.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace RESTful.CallBackService
{
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
            xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);  
        }
}
}
```

And this is my App_Start WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RESTful.CallBackService
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
        }
}
}
```

Can anyone see where Im going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried firing up [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and inspecting the HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling all the nitty-gritty of web-requests, you should concentrate on your business logic.  There is an excellent open source project called [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) that will handle all the nitty-gritty for you.  You then only need to send objects that get serialized for you into whatever [client(s)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) your using.  The web-client only receives your business objects in the handler, it doesn't care how (with what protocol) it arrived in.  If you control both ends, so much the better.

Example, to post an XML Object you use the [XmlServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/XmlServiceClient.cs)

```
var client = new XmlServiceClient("http://host");

HelloResponse response = client.Post(new Hello { Name = "World" });
```

See better documentation and explanation of the above [here.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client)  You will have registered the Hello DTO object to a web-service and it will be routed to the proper service based on the parameters like `Name`.

Example your host could be configured like: `host/hello/{Name}` for the above example, therefore a request just typed into your browser could have that url and a Hello object with the Name filled in will be given to your Hello web-service.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this project in any way?

Answer (score 0):

try loading xml from `Request.InputStream` which will contain raw post content, in this case your xml.